# Material-Button changing disabled button style

Tags: button, material-ui

How can you change the style of a disabled button in Material-UI using themes ?

The following [code](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-4dn6i) doesn't work

```
const theme = createMuiTheme({
  props: {
    // Name of the component 
    MuiButtonBase: {
      // The default props to change
      disableRipple: true // No more ripple, on the whole application !
    }
  },
  overrides: {
    MuiButton: {
      text: {
        color: "red"
      },
      disabled: {
        text: {
          color: "blue"
        }
      }
    }
  }
});

function DefaultProps() {
  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <Button disabled>Change default props</Button>
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The following works:

```
const theme = createMuiTheme({
  props: {
    // Name of the component 
    MuiButtonBase: {
      // The default props to change
      disableRipple: true // No more ripple, on the whole application !
    }
  },
  overrides: {
    MuiButton: {
      root: {
        color: "red",
        '&$disabled': {
           color: "blue"
       }
      },
    }
  }
});
```

[image: Edit Invisible Backdrop]